# Symfony2 access Doctrine Entity Manager in custom class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

UPDATE:

In case you need to work with Entity Manager in a custom class, you could go this way:

put this code in your bundle:

```php
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
require_once DIR . '/../../../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once DIR . '/../../../app/AppKernel.php';

class ApplicationBoot {
  private static $kernel;

  public static function getContainer() {
    if(self::$kernel instanceof \AppKernel) {
      if(!self::$kernel->getContainer() instanceof Container){
        self::$kernel->boot();
    }            
    return self::$kernel->getContainer();
  }

  $environment = 'prod';
  if (!array_key_exists('REMOTE_ADDR', $_SERVER) || in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1', 'localhost'))) {
    $environment = 'dev';
  }

  self::$kernel = new \AppKernel($environment, false);
  self::$kernel->boot();
  return self::$kernel->getContainer();
  }

  public static function shutDown() {
    self::$kernel->shutdown();
}}
```

So now you can access EntityManager:

```php
$container = ApplicationBoot::getContainer();
$entityManager = $container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
```

Comment: When you say "work with" are trying to pull it from the service container or trying to new the class?

Comment: That is not going to work.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like you replaced your question with an answer.  And yes you can do what your wrote but exposing the container as a global is frowned upon and is not needed.  Once you get a bit more comfortable with services then you will see what I am talking about.  I down voted your question mostly because by completely replacing the original question you have pretty much invalidated all the answers.

Comment: I am sorry. But it's only one way I can go. My custom class is called by external library which know nothing about Symfony and not related to it, so making custom class as a service couldn't help me.

Comment: Did they actually not think to include some way to easily do this? wow

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a service file like this:

```
arguments:
  entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Probably should be:

```
arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

UPDATE:

Based on some comments it appears that you are trying to do:

```
$job = new PostJob();
```

And expecting that entity manager will somehow be passed.  And that is just not the way things work.  You need to do:

```
$job = $this->get('postjob.service.id');
```

In order to have the Symfony 2 dependency injection work.  Review the chapter in the manual on services.  It might seem a bit over whelming at first but once you get a few services working then it becomes second nature.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you.
In my case I can't do $this->get('postjob.service.id'); but only new PostJob();
So how to access EM in this case?

Comment: Add some more info to your question so we can see where you calling PostJob from.  I'm guessing it is an entity which means you are going to need to refactor probably using Doctrine's life cycle capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

To load the `services.yml` from your bundle, you need to provide an [extension class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#importing-configuration-via-container-extensions):

```php
// src/Vendor/YourBundle/DedendencyInjection/VendorYourBundleExtension.php

namespace Vendor\YourBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader,
    Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;

class VendorYourBundleExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, maybe I go wrong way. I will not access PostJob as service, I just create new object of PostJob and would like to have entity manager object inside.